# overprint environment from beamer not working with graphbox

Tags: beamer, pdftex, overlays, incompatibility

I create a presentation with pdfLaTeX and the `beamer` document class. In the presentation graphics are shown step by step. The graphic for each step replaces the graphic from the preceding step. To this end, I use `beamer`'s `overprint` environment.

```
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe} % provides example-image-*
%\usepackage{graphbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{}
    before
    \pause
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<+|handout:0>\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
        \onslide<+|handout:0>\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}
        \onslide<+-|handout:1>\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works well. I get the following four slides:

[image: good result]

However, as soon as I add the package `graphbox` the example above stops working, that is, the generated PDF is not what I want. There is an additional slide and all but the last slide contain no graphic:

[image: bad result]

I really would like to use `graphbox` because of its easy vertical alignment (`\includegraphics[align=c]`). Is there a way to make `graphbox` work with `overprint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `graphbox` package redefines `\includegraphics` such that the included picture always occupies space (even if not visible). This changes the behavior of beamer overlays (see Sections 1.3 and 2.2 of [the package manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/graphbox/graphbox.pdf)) and causes your problem. Add the option `nobeamer` to the `graphbox` package to disable this behavior.

```
\usepackage[nobeamer]{graphbox}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. With `graphbox`' default behavior it might even be possible to cope without `overprint` using `\only` instead of `\onslide`.